# Linux C++ file write becomes slow when a different (POSIX) thread writes to a different file

Tags: linux, file, io

File write done to a SSD. Operating system Red-Hat 7.9

File is opened as
open(fileName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
https://linux.die.net/man/3/open

Written using write call (https://linux.die.net/man/2/write)

**Scenario 1**
A single thread writes to file A

**Scenario 2**
3 threads write to 3 different files

All above files are written to same file system(xfs)

**Observation** : Avg write time increases in scenario 2. This happens even if I try to keep TOTAL(i.e. addition of all 3 threads) data write rate same or smaller than scenario 1 rate.

**is this the expected behavior ?** if so what is the explanation.

**More info:**
16 core machine used with sufficient CPU and memory (i.e. they are NOT the bottle neck).
Written block size 104 (per single write).
Few result numbers (Program running WITHOUT CPU binding) :

Scenario 1 : 6540 writes per second. Avg time per write = 1.389 us

Scenario 2 : 1806 X 3 writes per second. Avg times per write = 1.894, 1.810, 1.881 us

*one other thing I noted is write time improves when they are run under isolated CPUs

Minimal Sample code :
Compiling "g++ -O3 Minimal.cpp  -lpthread"

Env variable THREAD_COUNT sets the concurrent thread count and SLEEP_TIME controls the write rate

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;


int64_t getMicroSecDiffFrom(const timeval& begin);

struct Stat
{
    atomic<uint64_t> consumedTime {0};
    atomic<uint64_t> sampleCount {0};
};

Stat g_stats[10];

void writeToFile(int32_t threadIndex)
{
    char fileName[128];
    snprintf(fileName, sizeof(fileName), "test_Data_Thd_%d", threadIndex);
    
    auto fd = open(fileName, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, S_IREAD|S_IWRITE|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH);
    if(fd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to create file [" << fileName << "]. " << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

    auto envVar = getenv("SLEEP_TIME");
    uint32_t sleepTime = 1000;
    if(envVar)
    {
        sleepTime = atoi(envVar);
    }

    char buf[104] = "dat123";
    uint64_t written = 0;
    while(true)
    {       
        timeval beg;
        gettimeofday(&beg, nullptr);
        if(write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) != sizeof(buf))
        {
            cerr << "Failed to write. Written =" << written << endl;
            exit(-2);
        }       
        g_stats[threadIndex].consumedTime.fetch_add(getMicroSecDiffFrom(beg), memory_order_relaxed);
        g_stats[threadIndex].sampleCount.fetch_add(1, memory_order_relaxed);

        written += sizeof(buf);

        if(sleepTime > 0)
        {
            usleep(sleepTime);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    thread t0(writeToFile, 0);
    
    int32_t threadCount = 0;
    auto envVar = getenv("THREAD_COUNT");
    if(envVar)
    {
        threadCount = atoi(envVar);
    }

    vector<thread> thds;
    for(auto i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
    {       
        thds.push_back(thread(writeToFile, i + 1));
    }

    string stat;
    int32_t round = 0;
    Stat runningAvg[10];
    while(true)
    {       
        stat.clear();
        round++;
        
        for(auto i = 0; i < (threadCount + 1); i++)
        {
            auto samples = g_stats[i].sampleCount.load(memory_order_relaxed);
            auto time = g_stats[i].consumedTime.load(memory_order_relaxed);
            if(samples > 0)
            {
                if(round > 5)
                {
                    runningAvg[i].consumedTime += time;
                    runningAvg[i].sampleCount += samples;
                }

                char buff[32];
                snprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), "%.3f(c=%lu RAvg=%.3f)\t", ((double) time) / samples, samples, 
                        ((double) runningAvg[i].consumedTime) / runningAvg[i].sampleCount);
                stat += buff;
                
                g_stats[i].sampleCount.store(0, memory_order_relaxed);
                g_stats[i].consumedTime.store(0, memory_order_relaxed);
            }

        }

        printf("\rWrite times(us) R=%d %s", round, stat.c_str());
        fflush(stdout);     
        sleep(1);
    }

    
    
    return 0;
}

inline int64_t getMicroSecDiff(const timeval& begin, const timeval& end)
{
    constexpr uint32_t MicroSecPerSec = 1000 * 1000;
    return (end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec) * MicroSecPerSec + (end.tv_usec - begin.tv_usec);
}

inline int64_t getMicroSecDiffFrom(const timeval& begin)
{
    timeval end;
    gettimeofday(&end, nullptr);
    
    return getMicroSecDiff(begin, end);
}
```

Comment: did you try to profile your code? I can highly recommend the hotspot tool, which is a  frontend to perf.

Comment: profiling gives time consumption in terms of CPU cycles. How do you propose profiling helps in this case ?

Comment: `iostat` will give disk rates and activity.

Comment: @aKumara You don't know what part is slow and why. Profiling is a quick measure to get an idea. Btw. perf is a profiler and a tracer and can do things like that: https://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#Tracepoints

Comment: Do you write files on the same file system and same SSD? Then the observed behavior should be expected. The bottleneck is usually the SSD hardware itself.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch he said he throttled the IO of the threads to be below the single thread throughput, if I understood correctly

Comment: The SSD has *physical* limitations, and most of them are not that fast (unless you bought an expensive one)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch of course. I am just saying that he used 3 threads and throttled them to be in total below the throughput of the single thread.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, all files written to the same file system on same SSD.

Comment: The numbers do not add up. 6540 writes per second is 153 us per write or 1.47 us per byte.

Comment: ... and that's something like 1% of normal SSD throughput, so something is fishy in your setup. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem, "The numbers do not add up...". Pls note that write loop has intentional usleep calls to control write rate.

Comment: sample code added

Comment: "intentional usleep" So the numbers are meaningless.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem, time taken for the write call is measured. i.e. usec time difference before and after each write call is measured. Then each threads avg is calaculated.

Comment: If you insert sleeps, time taken for a write call is a useless number. It tells you nothing about performance of real world programs.

Comment: "If you insert sleeps, time taken for a write call is a useless number." could you pls explain why ? sleep call is independent of write call.

Comment: Write *call* is only a small part of the entire write *operation*. Why measure it at all? I guess what happens in your situation is several threads trying to access the device at the same time. Only one can do so and others need to wait. This has nothing to do with device throughput, only with how fast data can be copied to its internal buffer (usually very fast) and this time can be reduced to virtually zero by using async IO. Once you saturate your write channel you will see a vastly different picture.

Comment: "Why measure it at all?" this is a sample program to elaborate the problem. Write call time is measured becoz it is the problem.

Comment: Here written data rate is low (well below Device capabilities), so there cannot be a race to access the SSD device (data written to OS level buffer and copied to SSD by a OS back ground process - pdflush or similar) .

Comment: I give up, I cannot reproduce your results. In my experiments write call time varies wildly (sometimes by a factor of 3) and multi-thread writes sometimes take more time than single-thread and sometimes less.